# AWS versioning - How to keep only 10 newest versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup, versioning

I using AWS CLI on Ubu Srv 16.04 LTS to make backup in S3 bucket every 30 minutes.

I have versioning enabled in the bucket properties.

I use this command to send files:

```
aws s3 cp DIR s3://BUCKET_NAME/ --recursive --region BUCKET_REGION
```

Is there any AWS CLI command that will allow me to save only the 10 newest versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt S3(or for that matter AWS CLI) supports this.
But you can use a trick using S3 Lifecycle policy.

You can use [Amazon S3 – Object Expiration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/) function:

S3’s new Object Expiration function allows you to define rules to schedule the removal of your objects after a pre-defined time period.

<strike>You mentioned you run this every 30 minutes. So after 300 minutes, there should be 10 versions, right? Now you can configure the above-mentioned function to run on objects older than 300 minutes, something like that</strike>

@michael-sqlbot mentioned in comments: Object expiration functions work on the unit of day. so need to wait for at-least 24hrs considering the qn situation of handling it in minutes.

But this approach should work, if we are considering days.

BTW, more on S3 Object expiration -> [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-expiration/)

#JustRandomThoughts

Comment: where you assume that the same _file_ is being overwritten everytime. It may be that there are multiple files, of which only a few got updated

Comment: Yes, this thought drifted through my mind, but I was in doubt whether --no-overwrite option has been implemented in s3 cp command. Couldnt find it on s3 cp doc page ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html ). But here https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2874

Comment: @raevilman object expiration has a configuration granularity of 1 day and objects may persist for up to 24 hours beyond their anticipated expiration.  It's a batch process.